# Using Lucene to query an RDBMS database

Tags: database, lucene.net, lucene

I've skimmed the docs for the Java version of Lucene, but I can't really see the top-level "this is how it works" info so far (I'm aware I need to RTFM, I just can't see the wood for the trees).

I understand Lucene uses search indexes to return results. As far as I know, it only returns "hits" from those indexes. If I haven't added an item of data when building the index then it won't be returned.

That's fine, so now I want to check the following assumption:

**Q: Does that mean that any data I want displayed on a search page needs to be added to the Lucene index?**

**I.e.**
If I want to search for `Product`s by things like sku, description, category name, etc, but I also want to display the `Customer` they belong to in search results, do I:

1. Make sure the Lucene index has the denormalised `Customer`'s name in the index.
2. Use the hits returned by Lucene to somehow query the database for the actual product records and use a `JOIN` to get the `Customer`'s name.

I assume it's option **1**, since I'm assuming there's no way to "join" the results of a Lucene query to an RDBMS, but wanted to ask it my assumptions about the general usage are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [BrokenGlass's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715109/using-lucene-to-query-an-rdbms-database/4715136#4715136), I've thought some more and am proposing the following to see if I'm on the right lines:

Basically, taking option 2 further, one could do the following:

1. Put only the data you want to search on into the Lucene index, plus some sort of key value (e.g. the PK of a table in your database).
2. Query Lucene to get a list of hits.
3. Using your data access layer of choice, build a query for your database that includes an `IN (value [, value])` predicate.
4. Get the results for that query from your database (which may well include `JOIN`s to other tables).
5. Put those results in a dictionary, using the PK of the resultset as the key.
6. Iterate the Lucene hits again in order, pulling the items from the dictionary using the PK so you can build a list of results in the order that Lucene returned the hits (i.e. sorted by relevance).
7. Display that "sorted" list of results to the user.

Of course steps 5 and 6 could be better, but for the sake of explanation I put that verbose method in my description. If the Lucene hits include some sort of "relevance" value, then you could attribute that to the resultset and perform a standard sort, but that's an exercise for the reader. :)

Could this be it?

Comment: this is what I would recommend for searching over a "large" data set with Lucene - if you don't have that much data you might as well put everything into your index though and not worry about it - if you do want to scale you must minimize the index though.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the index would only contain the fields you want to search on, not necessarily the ones you want to display. Indexes should be optimized to be as small as possible, to keep search performance good.

To be able to display more data add a field to your index that allows you to retrieve your full document/data, i.e. a unique key for your `Product` (product id?).

Comment: Ahh, so you propose option 2, then? I'm fine with that, but if I get a list back, I'd have to hit the database once for each item in the results to get the full details back, or have a potentially massive `IN ([PK])` statement that I build from the hits. I might answer my own question with that and see if it gets any votes to suggest I'm on the right lines - thanks for getting my brain working! :)

Comment: As always it depends - this approach is for optimizing search performance, but not display performance. In general though, especially with a paged results view, the hit for retrieving a few product details at a time is negligible compared to blowing up your lucene index

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to figure out the same problem, but I think that its too much work. I'm thinking of this as an alternative. Plse correct me if I'm wrong in my thinking!

Your situation is like this:
RDBMS product (many) <------> (many) Customer

Instead of putting only customer in lucene index to get product keys, and then query RDBMS with IN Query, I'd suggest, create the lucene index with the cartesian product of  Product as well as Customer.

Like
customer_1, product_1
customer_1, product_2
customer_2, product_2..

This way, when you are searching for a product in lucene, it will give both the customer as well as the products id.. and instead of joining them in RDBMS, you can simply look up those customers as well as products for more information from RDBMS, if there is a need. If you are using caching, then the additional details lookup cost will also go down.

Comment: I like this idea. I see your point - to put more information in the index in the first place. It does require a bit more forward-thinking, but if there's a good way to rebuild or update indexes in this way as the app is upgraded then it should work out fine.